# Pushing UIViewController above UITabBar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I have a `UIViewController` called `ListVC`. `ListVC` has a `UITabBar` that the user can switch tabs with. It also has `UINavigationController`.

In `ListVC` I have a button, that I want to push a new ViewController called `DetailVC` when it's pressed (with the `NavigationController`). I want to present `DeatilVC` without a `UITabBar`.

The problem is that when I'm using the `pushViewController(animated)` method, the view still has the `UITabBar`.

How can I push the view (I don't want to present it modally) above the `UITabBar`?

You can see an example of it on `Whatsapp` when selecting a chat from the chat list. Image:

[image: Imafe]

Code:

`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)`

Thank you!

Comment: @SPatel Value of type 'UITabBarController' has no member 'pushViewController'

Comment: the `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)` can't solve your problem. it's not true. maybe you did something else?

Comment: @pacification What do you mean? By default `pushViewController` pushes the view and keeps the tabBar

Comment: Embed tabBarcontroller in to navigationController

Comment: @SPatel What do you mean? Can you please explain a bit more (I'm not using storyboard)

Comment: @FS.O6, yes, it is. but you want to push above the tabbar, right? if you do just `pushViewController` you get the push under tabbar.

Comment: I've solved the priblem

Comment: Set application rootViewController with NavigationController.

Comment: And set tabBarController as root of NavigationController

Comment: Try self.tabBarController.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)

Comment: what does your storyboard look like?

Answer (score 9):

Write below code when you push:

```
yourViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

You can also hide tabbar on push from storyboard also. select view controller which you are going to push and check Hide Bottom Bar on Push:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't present the view above the tabbar. It's just hiding it (and without any animation).

Comment: are you presenting view controller or pushing?

Comment: Pushing. You can see what I'm trying to achieve for example in `Whatsapp`

Comment: I've added an image of what I'm trying to achieve. Please take a look

Comment: did you add below this code when pushing  `yourViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
`?

Comment: I've tried. It's just hiding the tabbar (even without an animation). I want to pushed view to be above its superview's tabbar

Answer (score 2):

1.Write below code when you push:

```
let yourVC = Storyboard.Main.storyboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! YourViewController
yourVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourVC, animated: true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've solved the problem. I had to add `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` twice before and after the push code:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed  = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

Comment: according to the docs `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` should called on the pushing vc, not from vc that pushed. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

Go to storyboard and check the `Hide Bottom Bar On Push`:

[image]

or just type in DeatilVC `viewDidLoad` method `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`.

Comment: It doesn't present the view above the tabbar. It's just hiding it (and without any animation).

Comment: I've added an image of what I'm trying to achieve. Please take a look

Comment: @FS.O6, still don't get the problem. maybe you have a video or gif example?

Comment: I don't want to hide the tabbar. I want to push a `VC` above it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: I've added an image of what I'm trying to achieve. Please take a look

Comment: I've added an image. That's exactly what I want to achieve. Not hiding the tabbar, pushing a `VC` above it

Comment: are you pushing to a navigation controller or viewcontroller???
if you are pushing a viewcontroller with a navigation controller try removing that navigationcontroller and push to viewcontroller

Comment: What do you mean? I'm pushing it like this: `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)`

Comment: so you are saying that you tabbar is getting hidden ?? and you don't want that tabbar get hidden??

Comment: It doesn't get hidden. But I don't want it to be hidden. I want to push the `detailVC` ABOVE the tabbar. Please take a look on the image I've added to the question

Comment: the above code perfectly works for that
you can hide bottom bar on push also


self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

Comment: Where should I add `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`? Let me try

Comment: Is `self` `ListVC` or `DetailVC`?

Comment: in your ListVC because you have your tabbar in ListVC right??

Comment: I want the tabbar to be just in `ListVC` and not to be in `DetailVC`

Comment: ok i understood you don't want to hide that tabbar(with animation) when you are pushing and you want it to be hidden in your detailVC

Comment: Using this code it will black in bottom.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS UINavigationViewController and UITabBar**

You have three options:

1. in storyboard: select ViewController -> Attributes Inspector -> Hide Bottom Bar On Push
2. in code: `vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`
3. in ViewController code:

```
public override var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool {
    get { return true }
    set { }
}
```